# Restrict Access to Web Apis in Azure AppServices to Azure Function app, while allowing access to other web apis and web pages to other services

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure AppService running ASP.NET Core for both web page and web api.

Currently, All web pages are available publicly and restricted via login using Azure AD.

Currently, All Web Apis are aslo available publicly, and restricted via client login credentials. These are accessed via 3rd party tool.

Now, a new Azure Function app needs to call new web APIs in the Azure AppService. The new web APIs must be only available to the Function app. The new Function app is hosted in the same region as the AppService, and managed by the same team.

What restrictions methods are available?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this. However, in both the cases you will need to enable [Regional VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) on the function app.

1. On the Web Api, enable the [Private Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint) feature. This will disable all public access and restrict access from within the VNET. This feature will require an unused subnet, which will then be used to allocate an inbound private IP Address. The Function App using Vnet Integration can access the Web Api (using Private Endpoint).

> NOTE: You will need to create 2 subnets, one for Vnet Integration and
> the other for private endpoint feature. Its preferable to have them in
> the same VNet.

2. On the Web Api, enable [access restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) and allow access to the subnet, to which the Function API is integrated with.

Answer (score -1):

> The new web APIs must be only available to the Function app.

For your requirement, you can use azure VNET to achieve, First, put your Web API in a azure VNET, then this API can not access by others. After that, but your function app in the VNET. Then you can only access the WEB API by the function app in the VNET.

Have a look of this official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: The problem is that the new web APIs and existin web apis and web pages are hosted in the same App Service.